# Using in /../ path in cmd console

Tags: path, cd

From what I'm studying I saw using `/../` in using `cd` command in cmd.

I know that "cd .. " goes one step up the directory.

But why would he/she use `/../`?

ex)

Let's say folder "C:\file" has "A" and "B" folders in it

Why not use:

```
cd C:\file\B
```

instead of

```
cd C:\file\A/../B
```

Just curious. If anybody knows why just tell me. You don't have to be specific but if you do, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for it. Both paths would theoretically be valid. It's just a question of efficiency. As a real world corny example: "I'm in the living room, and I want to go into the living room, so I'll just step into the next room and then back into the living room". v.s. "I'm in the living room and I'll just stay here".

In both cases you end up in the living room, but the stupid version makes you walk elsewhere before coming back - waste of time/energy.